# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." - Which loader is expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, create-react-app

I created a new react app with `create-react-app`. I try to use a package that written in react, I imported the default component but get a compiled error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@USER-NAME/any-package/src/index.tsx 12:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| export default (
>   <Provider data={data}>
|     <App />
|   </Provider>
```

what am I missing? Can't find a proper solution for this case.

`App.js`

```js
import "./App.css";
import ReactComponent from "@USER-NAME/any-package";

function App() {
  return <ReactComponent />;
}

export default App;
```

The main component that I import from the package:

`index.js`:

```js
import ReactComponent from "./src/index.tsx";

export default ReactComponent;
```

`index.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const data = {}

export default (
// getting the error about this line
  <Provider data={data}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

Any idea what should I add/update?

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app can't work with cjs packages out-of-the-box so you need an additional loader for packages like these.

Here's a thread in create-react-app's GitHub that will help you:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12700

EDIT: Can you try this code, export in the index.tsx is definitely incorrect

```js
// app.js
import "./App.css";
import ReactComponent from "@USER-NAME/any-package";

function App() {
  return <ReactComponent />;
}

export default App;

// index.js
import ReactComponent from "./src/index.tsx";

export default ReactComponent;

// index.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const data = {};

const ProviderComponent = () => (
  <Provider data={data}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

export default ProviderComponent;
```

Comment: I don't have `.csj` files in that package.

Comment: @ESI then what do you have on line 12 in the './node_modules/@USER-NAME/any-package/src/index.tsx'?

Comment: The file is `.tsx` file, is that the same?

Comment: and the `source-map-loader` was installed by `create-react-app` automatically as a dependency package, what do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: @ESI, create-react-app clearly points out where the problem is, it's line 12 caret position 2. If there's `require()` or `module.exports = ...` then it's a commonJS. Or there can be import of commonJS module. Can you provide more info on what's on the line 12? :)

Comment: Sure, the code was attached, the file name is `index.tsx` and the line 12 is `<Provider data={data}>`.

Comment: @ESI, ok, then it's an import from react-redux. Please try to go into node_modules and check that Provider is not a commonJS module. One of the possible solutions would be to downgrade or upgrade version of react-redux package in your package.json

Comment: Seems I get the failure also if I return a blank component like `<></>`. Seems a global config or something is missing, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @ESI, oh, I think the issue is that you just cannot export component this way. You're trying to do `export default (<SomeComponent><SomeComponent/>)`. 
Try something like `export default function Foo() { return (<Provider></Provider>) }`

Comment: I have tried it but the issue is still exists...

Comment: I've edited the answer, can you try that code?

Comment: Still get the same issue...